# Missing _icon option and _icon.classList when using Leaflet.markercluster with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Can someone please explain to me why when I move point from one layer to another by doing this:

```
var previousLayer = activeItem.getLayers()[0];

activeItem.removeLayer(previousLayer); // activeItem is FeatureGroup
mapItems.addLayer(previousLayer); // mapItems is MarkerClusterGroup
```

And then try to change a marker class with:

```
previousLayer._icon.classList.remove('marker-active');
previousLayer._icon.classList.add('marker-shown');
```

I get and error that _icon is null when that marker goes inside a visible cluster on the map?

Is it some kind of MarkerCluster bug or I am missing something?

P.S. I tried to find parent cluster, cycle through all markers inside it and all of those markers don't have _icon option...

```
angular.forEach(mapItems.getVisibleParent(previousLayer)._markers, function (marker) {
     console.log(marker._icon); // error every time
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it some kind of MarkerCluster bug or I am missing something?

No. If you haven't noticed before, **anything with a _ in front of it is a private variable** in Leaflet terminology. That means, if you rely on anything with a _ in front of it, it will easily break when you

- upgrade Leaflet
- use plugins
- use a different browser

And this breakage is not Leaflet's fault, but your own.

Answer: don't use `._icon`, and in this case, introspect the marker with `console.log` to find out what type it is.